# Laravel 8.0: laravel.log file not found using storage_path()

Tags: php, laravel, logging, scheduled-tasks, laravel-8

I'm trying to write a Laravel 8.0 task that renames the default log file every week and makes another empty file. I'm using a Debian 10 virtual machine as a testing environment.

Here's my  `handle()` code:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$baseLog = "/laravel.log";
$oldLog = storage_path("logs".$baseLog);
$renamedLog = storage_path("logs"."/log_".$now->day."_"
    .$now->month."_".$now->year.".log");

Storage::move($oldLog, $renamedLog);
Storage::delete($oldLog);
Storage::put(storage_path("logs".$baseLog), "");
```

The problem is that Laravel
says...

> File not found at path: var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: When you move the file, it's moving it completely, not copying it. It won't exist for the `delete` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly pointed out, I called delete on a moved file (my bad) but the error happened before, while trying to locate the laravel.log.

After adding an exists check, I noticed the storage path returned has an "/app" so  I've just created another disk instance in `config/filesystems`

```
 'log' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('logs'),
        ],
```

and then I could finally resolve my issue like that:

```
$baseLog = "/laravel.log";
    if(Storage::disk('log')->exists($baseLog)){
       $now = Carbon::now();
       $renamedLog ="/log_".$now->day."_".$now->month."_".$now->year.".log";
       Storage::disk('log')->move($baseLog, $renamedLog);
       Storage::disk('log')->put($baseLog, "");
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add check for file exists and not use delete - because you **move** file:

```
$baseLog = "/laravel.log";
$oldLog = storage_path("logs".$baseLog);
if(Storage::exists($oldLog)){
  $now = Carbon::now();
  $renamedLog = storage_path("logs"."/log_".$now->day."_".$now->month."_".$now->year.".log");
  Storage::move($oldLog, $renamedLog);
  Storage::put(storage_path("logs".$baseLog), "");
}
```

Or, if this is not for studying, use package for log rotate, e.g. [this](https://github.com/cesargb/laravel-logs-rotate)